# Python requests зависание парсера

Tags: python, requests

Есть парсер, который написан на requests + lxml. Он парсит около 25к страниц. Периодически сайт отклоняет соединение, поэтому я сделал бесконечную отправку страниц с некоторым ожиданием:

Код:

```
def request(url):
    global cookies, headers
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
        assert (r.status_code == 200), ("Ошибка, Код ответа: ", r.status_code, url)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(5)
        return request(url)
    else:
        return r
```

При парсинге возникали такие ошибки, которые обрабатывались:

```
1. ('Connection broken: OSError("(10054, \'WSAECONNRESET\')",)', OSError("(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')",))
 2. HTTPSConnectionPool(host='store.steampowered.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /app/211204/Phantasy_Star_III_Generations_of_Doom/?snr=1_7_7_230_150_903 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')",),))
```

Это последние ошибки, которые были видны.

По сути, метод должен срабатывать каждые 5 секунд, и если выкидывает ошибку выдавать ее. Но у меня парсер просто зависает.  И я ничего не могу придумать, как решить данную проблему.
Кстати он работает в 25 потоках.

Comment: Лучше печатайте url и покажите url, который зависает

Comment: чтобы уловить url, необходимо выполнить в 1 поток, а это ой как долго). Я запустил, прошло 4%. К утру отпишусь